# Wordpress AJAX Form

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have the oddest issue and I have a feeling I am missing something easy. I am trying to process a form through Wordpress and AJAX. But when pointed to the right url it gives me a 400 error. I have a feeling I have my action setup wrong or something. The processing function is a method in the same class called process_registration_form.

```
//JS
$('#user-registration').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var registrationForm = jQuery(this).serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
          action:  'tribe_process_registration_form',
          type:    "POST",
          url:     tribe_process_user_registration.ajaxurl,
          data:    registrationForm,
          success: function(data) {
             console.log(data);
             //jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
          }
        });
});


//PHP
wp_enqueue_script( 'tribe_process_user_registration', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/tribe-product-gifting-public.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'tribe_process_user_registration', 'tribe_process_user_registration', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

add_action('wp_ajax_tribe_process_user_registration', array($this,'process_registration_form'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_tribe_process_user_registration', array($this,'process_registration_form'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't thing there is any issue in the above code but might be i have missing something. so here is the way i can do my ajax call.

**The enqueue the script file with wp function.**

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'pc-frontend-js', plugins_url( 'Scripts/front-end.js', __FILE__ ), false );

   wp_localize_script( 'pc-frontend-js', 'pc_var_arguments', array(
          'woopb_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('woopb_nonce'),
          'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
      )
   );
```

**Ajax call**

```
function callback_function(quantity) { 
    var condition = 'ajax_callback_condition'; 
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:  pc_var_arguments.ajax_url, 
        type : 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {
            action : 'ajax_callback_action',
            condition :condition,
            data : data,
        },
        success : function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }   
    }); 
};
```

**Hooks for ajax**

```
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_callback_action', array($this,'callback_function' ));
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_callback_action', array($this,'callback_function' ));
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up figuring this out it was in the add actions for the wp_ajax and nopriv adds. I just haven't had time to post about it.